# Configuring Inbound Websphere MQ in TomEE with EJB 2 MDBs

Tags: ibm-mq, ejb-2.x, tomcat8, apache-tomee

I have a project where I'm trying to deploy EJB 2 message driven beans (MDBs) in TomEE 1.7. I need these MDBs to connect and read messages from two Websphere MQs. However I couldn't find enough documentation on the Internet. From whatever I could parse together from [Websphere MQ configuration in JBoss](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/Deploy_the_WebSphere_MQ_Resource_Adapter.html) I've created the following

```
<Resource id="wmqRA" type="com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl">
    connectionConcurrency=5  
    maxConnections=10 
    logWriterEnabled=true 
    reconnectionRetryCount=5 
    reconnectionRetryInterval=300000 
    traceEnabled=false 
    traceLevel=3
```

```
<Resource id="jms/ABC"  type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl">
    TransactionSupport=none 
    ResourceAdapter=wmqRA 
    HostName=10.190.129.132   
    Port=1414 
    QueueManager=<QueueManagerName>
    Channel=<ChannelName>
    TransportType=Client
    UserName=mqm
    Password=abc
  </Resource>

<Container id="wmq" type="MESSAGE">
    ResourceAdapter=wmqRA
    MessageListenerInterface=javax.jms.MessageListener
    ActivationSpecClass=com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ActivationSpecImpl
</Container>

<Resource id="wmq-javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory"  type="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedQueueConnectionFactoryImpl">
TransactionSupport=xa 
ResourceAdapter=wmqRA
```

```
<Resource id="wmq-javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory"  type="javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedTopicConnectionFactoryImpl">
TransactionSupport=xa 
ResourceAdapter=wmqRA 
</Resource>

<Resource id="queue_id" type="javax.jms.Queue"  class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy"> 
arbitraryProperties 
baseQueueManagerName=<QueueManagerName>
baseQueueName=<QueueName>
CCSID=1208 
encoding=NATIVE 
expiry=APP 
failIfQuiesce=true 
persistence=APP 
priority=APP 
readAheadClosePolicy=ALL 
targetClient=JMS 
</Resource>`
```

The connections get established to the queue manager (Verified by using runmqsc) but the EJBs don't get triggered/created when messages are added to the queues.

Any direction would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution after many trial and errors. It looks like we need to specify  in ejb-jar.xml for EJB2 to work with Tomee.

Use this

```
<message-driven>
        <ejb-name>beanName</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>beanClass</ejb-class>
        <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
        <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
        <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
        <activation-config>
             <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</activation-config-property-value>
             </activation-config-property>
             <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>*queueName*</activation-config-property-value>
             </activation-config-property>
             <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>channel</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>*channelName*</activation-config-property-value>
             </activation-config-property>
             <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>hostName</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>*hostName*</activation-config-property-value>
             </activation-config-property>
             <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>port</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>1414</activation-config-property-value>
             </activation-config-property>
             <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>queueManager</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>*queueManager*</activation-config-property-value>
             </activation-config-property>
             <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>transportType</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>CLIENT</activation-config-property-value>
             </activation-config-property>
           </activation-config>
```